# Is "while" here duration of time or contrastively used?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And this has direct repercussions at the individual level: households
> can reduce the cost of electricity and gas bills, and improve their
> health and comfort, **while** companies can increase their
> competitiveness and their productivity.

As I know, ***while*** has two meanings.

> 1. We must have been burgled while we were asleep. (duration of time)
> 2. While Tom’s very good at science, his brother is absolutely hopeless. (contrast)

I wonder what the answer is.

Comment: for me duration of time *kinda-* = contrast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am inclined to understand "while" in the sentence below:

> Households can reduce the cost of electricity and gas bills, and improve their health and comfort, **while** companies can increase their competitiveness and their productivity.

as expressing simultaneity of concepts, though not of events. There is no contrast between the two ideas, as there is in OP's sentence (2). At the same time, it does not express actual time, as in OP's sentence (1).

It is equivalent to "and at the same time," or "and in turn," but the time is not physical. It is more of a discursive organizer than an actual conjunction of time.